# Bootstrap4 Carousel caption background color not working for me

Tags: css

I'm trying to get an opaque background on the carousel caption text. A similar problem was reported in February so I think my code format is correct. Any comments are appreciated as I can't think of anything else to try.

```
.carousel-item { 
  height: 65vh; 
  min-height: 300px; 
  background: no-repeat center center scroll; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover; 
}

.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65%);
}
```

Comment: Unclear what the problem is supposed to be. Setting a background for `.carousel-caption` in the browser dev tools for the example under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-captions works absolutely as expected. Instead of showing a mere CSS snippet, you need to provide a proper [mre] of your problem when asking for help on stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter should be between 0 and 1. In your case, you chose the value 0,65% which is equivalent to 0,0065, that's why you cannot notice the color.
If you want to set it to 65% of opacity, either you set it to **65%** or to **0,65**.

For more informations, check this URL :
[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp#:~:text=RGBA%20color%20values%20are%20an,and%201.0%20(fully%20opaque)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp#:%7E:text=RGBA%20color%20values%20are%20an,and%201.0%20(fully%20opaque)).